# 18.04 lock screen stopped working - screen freezes

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen

[image]

When I try to lock the screen it just freezes. It is not possible to log on again. It used to work perfectly and suddenly it does not. However, I am not aware of any recent updates or similar.

I would try to reinstall the component that is responsible for locking the screen. Which one would that be?

Comment: @PRATAP yes, but with the same buggy behavior

Comment: I exactly followed these steps and it solved the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem appeared again.

Comment: Seems like I have the same problem. Ctrl-Alt-F1 helps temporarily, as it allows me to log in back. But I'd like a proper fix. Also applications dock (on the left) breaks at the same time. Unfortunately, I haven't noticed which particular update brought this behavior, but it was something from last month. And I have it on two different machines, both ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Update the system with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` or you can do fresh installation of [18.04.2](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/bionic/daily-live/current/).

Answer (score 1):

You can track the bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock/+bug/1799293). `Dash to Dock` Gnome extension is causing it.

Upgrading packages helped for me.

Also known temporary workarounds:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> after locking to repaint screen.
2. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> twice to hide screen content (the dock will still be visible, though)
3. after logging back <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r`, enter. To reset `Gnome` and fix broken dock.

Comment: It seems more likely to be correct but not a proper answer and seems as comment. Please provide a detail answer with describing which package to upgrade and how to otherwise it will be [deleted](https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: The bug was in `dash-to-dock`. I don't know which package contains it, probably `gnome-software`. Just update all packages. Deleting the only answer is surely useful thing to do, go on.

Comment: I realized that the upgrade fixed almost the problem, but if the laptop is docked I still have it.

Comment: Trying to upgrade to linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic

Comment: Upgrading kernel won't help. Try installing latest dash to dock or disable it completely. Also note, that `ubuntu dock` is a derivative of `dash to dock`, so take a look at it, if it is enabled in your system (it is optional).

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1656658

I've been getting a lot of screen hangs.

try opening a terminal and enter 
$dmesg -w

This will show you the last error... 
also consider getting your sys info with 
$inxi -Fxz

good luck!